# How to connect Apache Httpd to multiple Tomcat instances using mod_jk in Oracle Linux?

Tags: apache, tomcat

I am trying to set up an **Apache httpd + multiple Tomcat instances** configuration using the mod_jk module in Oracle Linux R7U9. The purpose is for Apache httpd to receive requests over a single external IP address (192.168.157.130) and single domain (artemis.com) then delegate processing of requests to different Tomcat instances.
The Tomcat instances are:

1. demo - where an app is deployed with context path /bar
2. expo - where an app is deployed with context path /foo

I have tried to incorporate some of the solutions offered here in SO in similar situation. However, when I try to access the apps **/bar** and **/foo**, I kept getting the below error messages.

What could be missing in my configurations? Are there any Apache component that I need to install?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Browser error message

```
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

Mod JK error log

```
 95 [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3591): mod_jk/1.2.48 initialized
 96 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (177): uri map dump after extension stripping: id=1, index=0 file='(null)' reject_unsafe=0 reload=60 modified=0 checked=0
 97 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 0: size=0 nosize=0 capacity=0
 98 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 1: size=0 nosize=0 capacity=0
 99 [debug] uri_worker_map_switch::jk_uri_worker_map.c (601): Switching uri worker map from index 0 to index 1
100 [debug] wc_get_worker_for_name::jk_worker.c (119): found a worker bar
101 [debug] wc_get_name_for_type::jk_worker.c (303): Found worker type 'ajp13'
102 [debug] extension_fix_activation::jk_uri_worker_map.c (486): Checking extension for worker bar of type ajp13 (2)
103 [debug] wc_get_worker_for_name::jk_worker.c (119): found a worker foo
104 [debug] wc_get_name_for_type::jk_worker.c (303): Found worker type 'ajp13'
105 [debug] extension_fix_activation::jk_uri_worker_map.c (486): Checking extension for worker foo of type ajp13 (2)
106 [debug] wc_get_worker_for_name::jk_worker.c (119): found a worker bar
107 [debug] wc_get_name_for_type::jk_worker.c (303): Found worker type 'ajp13'
108 [debug] extension_fix_activation::jk_uri_worker_map.c (486): Checking extension for worker bar of type ajp13 (2)
109 [debug] wc_get_worker_for_name::jk_worker.c (119): found a worker foo
110 [debug] wc_get_name_for_type::jk_worker.c (303): Found worker type 'ajp13'
111 [debug] extension_fix_activation::jk_uri_worker_map.c (486): Checking extension for worker foo of type ajp13 (2)
112 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (177): uri map dump after extension stripping: id=2, index=0 file='(null)' reject_unsafe=0 reload=60 modified=0 checked=0
113 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 0: size=0 nosize=0 capacity=0
114 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 1: size=4 nosize=0 capacity=4
115 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (196): NEXT (1) map #0: uri=/bar/* worker=bar context=/bar/* source=JkMount type=Wildchar len=6
116 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (196): NEXT (1) map #1: uri=/foo/* worker=foo context=/foo/* source=JkMount type=Wildchar len=6
117 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (196): NEXT (1) map #2: uri=/bar worker=bar context=/bar source=JkMount type=Exact len=4
118 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (196): NEXT (1) map #3: uri=/foo worker=foo context=/foo source=JkMount type=Exact len=4
119 [debug] uri_worker_map_switch::jk_uri_worker_map.c (601): Switching uri worker map from index 0 to index 1
120 [debug] jk_shm_close::jk_shm.c (744): Closed shared memory /var/cache/httpd/mod_jk/jk.shm.7403 childs=1
121 [debug] jk_set_time_fmt::jk_util.c (486): Pre-processed log time stamp format is '[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] '
122 [debug] dump_options::mod_jk.c (665): JkOption 'ForwardURICompat' set in server 'artemis.com:80'
123 [debug] dump_options::mod_jk.c (673): JkOption 'ForwardURIEscaped' set in server 'artemis.com:80'
124 [debug] dump_options::mod_jk.c (697): JkOption 'ForwardKeySize' set in server 'artemis.com:80' (default)
125 [debug] uri_worker_map_open::jk_uri_worker_map.c (897): rule map size is 0
126 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (177): uri map dump after map open: id=0, index=0 file='(null)' reject_unsafe=0 reload=60 modified=0 checked=0
127 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 0: size=0 nosize=0 capacity=0
128 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 1: size=0 nosize=0 capacity=0
129 [debug] jk_set_time_fmt::jk_util.c (486): Pre-processed log time stamp format is '[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] '
130 [debug] dump_options::mod_jk.c (665): JkOption 'ForwardURICompat' set in server 'artemis.com [_default_:8443]'
131 [debug] dump_options::mod_jk.c (673): JkOption 'ForwardURIEscaped' set in server 'artemis.com [_default_:8443]'
132 [debug] dump_options::mod_jk.c (697): JkOption 'ForwardKeySize' set in server 'artemis.com [_default_:8443]' (default)
133 [debug] jk_set_time_fmt::jk_util.c (486): Pre-processed log time stamp format is '[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] '
134 [debug] dump_options::mod_jk.c (665): JkOption 'ForwardURICompat' set in server 'artemis.com [*:80]'
135 [debug] dump_options::mod_jk.c (673): JkOption 'ForwardURIEscaped' set in server 'artemis.com [*:80]'
136 [debug] dump_options::mod_jk.c (697): JkOption 'ForwardKeySize' set in server 'artemis.com [*:80]' (default)
137 [debug] uri_worker_map_open::jk_uri_worker_map.c (897): rule map size is 4
138 [debug] uri_worker_map_add::jk_uri_worker_map.c (856): exact rule '/bar=bar' source 'JkMount' was added
139 [debug] uri_worker_map_add::jk_uri_worker_map.c (847): wildchar rule '/bar/*=bar' source 'JkMount' was added
140 [debug] uri_worker_map_add::jk_uri_worker_map.c (856): exact rule '/foo=foo' source 'JkMount' was added
141 [debug] uri_worker_map_add::jk_uri_worker_map.c (847): wildchar rule '/foo/*=foo' source 'JkMount' was added
142 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (177): uri map dump after map open: id=0, index=0 file='(null)' reject_unsafe=0 reload=60 modified=0 checked=0
143 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 0: size=0 nosize=0 capacity=0
144 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 1: size=4 nosize=0 capacity=4
145 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (196): NEXT (1) map #0: uri=/bar/* worker=bar context=/bar/* source=JkMount type=Wildchar len=6
146 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (196): NEXT (1) map #1: uri=/foo/* worker=foo context=/foo/* source=JkMount type=Wildchar len=6
147 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (196): NEXT (1) map #2: uri=/bar worker=bar context=/bar source=JkMount type=Exact len=4
148 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (196): NEXT (1) map #3: uri=/foo worker=foo context=/foo source=JkMount type=Exact len=4
149 [debug] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3529): Setting default connection pool max size to 1
150 [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (500): Adding property 'worker.list' with value 'bar,foo' to map.
151 [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (500): Adding property 'worker.bar.port' with value '8209' to map.
152 [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (500): Adding property 'worker.bar.host' with value '192.168.157.130' to map.
153 [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (500): Adding property 'worker.bar.type' with value 'ajp13' to map.
154 [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (500): Adding property 'worker.foo.port' with value '8309' to map.
155 [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (500): Adding property 'worker.foo.host' with value '192.168.157.130' to map.
156 [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (500): Adding property 'worker.foo.type' with value 'ajp13' to map.
157 [debug] jk_map_resolve_references::jk_map.c (782): Checking for references with prefix worker. with wildcard (recursion 1)
158 [debug] jk_shm_calculate_size::jk_shm.c (142): JK_SHM_SLOT_SIZE defined as 384, need at least 384
159 [debug] jk_shm_calculate_size::jk_shm.c (176): shared memory will contain 2 ajp workers and 0 lb workers with 0 members
160 [debug] do_shm_open::jk_shm.c (621): Truncated shared memory to 1152
161 [debug] do_shm_open::jk_shm.c (668): Initialized shared memory /var/cache/httpd/mod_jk/jk.shm.7403 size=1152 free=768 addr=0x7f88473a0000
162 [debug] do_shm_open_lock::jk_shm.c (531): Opened shared memory lock /var/cache/httpd/mod_jk/jk.shm.7403.lock
163 [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (598): Dump of map 3: 'ServerRoot' -> '/etc/httpd'
164 [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (598): Dump of map 3: 'worker.list' -> 'bar,foo'
165 [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (598): Dump of map 3: 'worker.bar.port' -> '8209'
166 [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (598): Dump of map 3: 'worker.bar.host' -> '192.168.157.130'
167 [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (598): Dump of map 3: 'worker.bar.type' -> 'ajp13'
168 [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (598): Dump of map 3: 'worker.foo.port' -> '8309'
169 [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (598): Dump of map 3: 'worker.foo.host' -> '192.168.157.130'
170 [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (598): Dump of map 3: 'worker.foo.type' -> 'ajp13'
171 [debug] build_worker_map::jk_worker.c (249): creating worker bar
172 [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (153): about to create instance bar of ajp13
173 [debug] ajp_worker_factory::jk_ajp_common.c (3218): ajp worker 'bar' type=2 created
174 [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (166): about to validate and init bar
175 [debug] ajp_validate::jk_ajp_common.c (2862): worker bar target is '192.168.157.130:8209'
176 [debug] jk_ajp_push::jk_ajp_common.c (1190): syncing shm for ajp worker 'bar' from mem (0->0) [0->0]
177 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3076): (bar) setting endpoint options:
178 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3080): keepalive:              0
179 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3084): socket timeout:         0
180 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3088): socket connect timeout: 0
181 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3092): buffer size:            0
182 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3096): pool timeout:           0
183 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3100): ping timeout:           10000
184 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3104): connect timeout:        0
185 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3108): reply timeout:          0
186 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3112): prepost timeout:        0
187 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3116): recovery options:       0
188 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3120): retries:                2
189 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3124): max packet size:        8192
190 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3128): retry interval:         100
191 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3132): busy limit:         0
192 [debug] ajp_create_endpoint_cache::jk_ajp_common.c (2932): (bar) setting connection pool size to 1 with min 1 and acquire timeout 200
193 [debug] build_worker_map::jk_worker.c (249): creating worker foo
194 [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (153): about to create instance foo of ajp13
195 [debug] ajp_worker_factory::jk_ajp_common.c (3218): ajp worker 'foo' type=2 created
196 [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (166): about to validate and init foo
197 [debug] ajp_validate::jk_ajp_common.c (2862): worker foo target is '192.168.157.130:8309'
198 [debug] jk_ajp_push::jk_ajp_common.c (1190): syncing shm for ajp worker 'foo' from mem (0->0) [0->0]
199 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3076): (foo) setting endpoint options:
200 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3080): keepalive:              0
201 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3084): socket timeout:         0
202 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3088): socket connect timeout: 0
203 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3092): buffer size:            0
204 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3096): pool timeout:           0
205 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3100): ping timeout:           10000
206 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3104): connect timeout:        0
207 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3108): reply timeout:          0
208 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3112): prepost timeout:        0
209 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3116): recovery options:       0
210 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3120): retries:                2
211 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3124): max packet size:        8192
212 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3128): retry interval:         100
213 [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (3132): busy limit:         0
214 [debug] ajp_create_endpoint_cache::jk_ajp_common.c (2932): (foo) setting connection pool size to 1 with min 1 and acquire timeout 200
215 [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3591): mod_jk/1.2.48 initialized
216 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (177): uri map dump after extension stripping: id=1, index=0 file='(null)' reject_unsafe=0 reload=60 modified=0 checked=0
217 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 0: size=0 nosize=0 capacity=0
218 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 1: size=0 nosize=0 capacity=0
219 [debug] uri_worker_map_switch::jk_uri_worker_map.c (601): Switching uri worker map from index 0 to index 1
220 [debug] wc_get_worker_for_name::jk_worker.c (119): found a worker bar
221 [debug] wc_get_name_for_type::jk_worker.c (303): Found worker type 'ajp13'
222 [debug] extension_fix_activation::jk_uri_worker_map.c (486): Checking extension for worker bar of type ajp13 (2)
223 [debug] wc_get_worker_for_name::jk_worker.c (119): found a worker foo
224 [debug] wc_get_name_for_type::jk_worker.c (303): Found worker type 'ajp13'
225 [debug] extension_fix_activation::jk_uri_worker_map.c (486): Checking extension for worker foo of type ajp13 (2)
226 [debug] wc_get_worker_for_name::jk_worker.c (119): found a worker bar
227 [debug] wc_get_name_for_type::jk_worker.c (303): Found worker type 'ajp13'
228 [debug] extension_fix_activation::jk_uri_worker_map.c (486): Checking extension for worker bar of type ajp13 (2)
229 [debug] wc_get_worker_for_name::jk_worker.c (119): found a worker foo
230 [debug] wc_get_name_for_type::jk_worker.c (303): Found worker type 'ajp13'
231 [debug] extension_fix_activation::jk_uri_worker_map.c (486): Checking extension for worker foo of type ajp13 (2)
232 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (177): uri map dump after extension stripping: id=2, index=0 file='(null)' reject_unsafe=0 reload=60 modified=0 checked=0
233 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 0: size=0 nosize=0 capacity=0
234 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 1: size=4 nosize=0 capacity=4
235 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (196): NEXT (1) map #0: uri=/bar/* worker=bar context=/bar/* source=JkMount type=Wildchar len=6
236 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (196): NEXT (1) map #1: uri=/foo/* worker=foo context=/foo/* source=JkMount type=Wildchar len=6
237 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (196): NEXT (1) map #2: uri=/bar worker=bar context=/bar source=JkMount type=Exact len=4
238 [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (196): NEXT (1) map #3: uri=/foo worker=foo context=/foo source=JkMount type=Exact len=4
239 [debug] uri_worker_map_switch::jk_uri_worker_map.c (601): Switching uri worker map from index 0 to index 1
240 [debug] do_shm_open::jk_shm.c (678): Attached shared memory /var/cache/httpd/mod_jk/jk.shm.7403 [2] size=1152 workers=1 free=0 addr=0x7f88473a0000
241 [debug] do_shm_open_lock::jk_shm.c (472): Duplicated shared memory lock /var/cache/httpd/mod_jk/jk.shm.7403.lock
242 [debug] jk_child_init::mod_jk.c (3474): Initialized mod_jk/1.2.48
243 [debug] do_shm_open::jk_shm.c (678): Attached shared memory /var/cache/httpd/mod_jk/jk.shm.7403 [3] size=1152 workers=1 free=0 addr=0x7f88473a0000
244 [debug] do_shm_open_lock::jk_shm.c (472): Duplicated shared memory lock /var/cache/httpd/mod_jk/jk.shm.7403.lock
245 [debug] jk_child_init::mod_jk.c (3474): Initialized mod_jk/1.2.48
246 [debug] do_shm_open::jk_shm.c (678): Attached shared memory /var/cache/httpd/mod_jk/jk.shm.7403 [4] size=1152 workers=1 free=0 addr=0x7f88473a0000
247 [debug] do_shm_open_lock::jk_shm.c (472): Duplicated shared memory lock /var/cache/httpd/mod_jk/jk.shm.7403.lock
248 [debug] jk_child_init::mod_jk.c (3474): Initialized mod_jk/1.2.48
249 [debug] do_shm_open::jk_shm.c (678): Attached shared memory /var/cache/httpd/mod_jk/jk.shm.7403 [5] size=1152 workers=1 free=0 addr=0x7f88473a0000
250 [debug] do_shm_open_lock::jk_shm.c (472): Duplicated shared memory lock /var/cache/httpd/mod_jk/jk.shm.7403.lock
251 [debug] jk_child_init::mod_jk.c (3474): Initialized mod_jk/1.2.48
252 [debug] do_shm_open::jk_shm.c (678): Attached shared memory /var/cache/httpd/mod_jk/jk.shm.7403 [6] size=1152 workers=1 free=0 addr=0x7f88473a0000
253 [debug] do_shm_open_lock::jk_shm.c (472): Duplicated shared memory lock /var/cache/httpd/mod_jk/jk.shm.7403.lock
254 [debug] jk_child_init::mod_jk.c (3474): Initialized mod_jk/1.2.48
255 [debug] jk_servlet_normalize::jk_util.c (2184): URI on entering jk_servlet_normalize: [/bar/]
256 [debug] jk_servlet_normalize::jk_util.c (2278): URI on exiting jk_servlet_normalize: [/bar/]
257 [debug] map_uri_to_worker_ext::jk_uri_worker_map.c (1167): Attempting to map URI '/bar/' from 4 maps
258 [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (977): Attempting to map context URI '/bar/*=bar' source 'JkMount'
259 [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (990): Found a wildchar match '/bar/*=bar'
260 [debug] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2821): Into handler jakarta-servlet worker=bar r->proxyreq=0
261 [debug] wc_get_worker_for_name::jk_worker.c (119): found a worker bar
262 [debug] wc_maintain::jk_worker.c (352): Maintaining worker bar
263 [debug] wc_maintain::jk_worker.c (352): Maintaining worker foo
264 [debug] wc_get_name_for_type::jk_worker.c (303): Found worker type 'ajp13'
265 [debug] init_ws_service::mod_jk.c (1178): Service protocol=HTTP/1.1 method=GET ssl=false host=(null) addr=192.168.157.1 name=192.168.157.130 port=80 auth=(null) user=(null) laddr=192.168.157.130 raddr=192.168.157.1 uaddr=192.168.157.1 uri=/ba        r/
266 [debug] ajp_get_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (3356): (bar) acquired connection pool slot=0 after 0 retries
267 [debug] ajp_marshal_into_msgb::jk_ajp_common.c (680): (bar) ajp marshaling done
268 [debug] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2587): processing bar with 2 retries
269 [debug] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1718): (bar) no usable connection found, will create a new one.
270 [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (673): socket TCP_NODELAY set to On
271 [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (797): trying to connect socket 45 to 192.168.157.130:8209
272 [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (815): connect to 192.168.157.130:8209 failed (errno=13)
273 [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1064): (bar) Failed opening socket to (192.168.157.130:8209) (errno=13)
274 [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1724): (bar) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=13)
275 [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2774): (bar) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=1)
276 [debug] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2623): (bar) retry 1, sleeping for 100 ms before retrying
277 [debug] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1718): (bar) no usable connection found, will create a new one.
278 [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (673): socket TCP_NODELAY set to On
279 [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (797): trying to connect socket 45 to 192.168.157.130:8209
280 [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (815): connect to 192.168.157.130:8209 failed (errno=13)
281 [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1064): (bar) Failed opening socket to (192.168.157.130:8209) (errno=13)
282 [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1724): (bar) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=13)
283 [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2774): (bar) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=2)
284 [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2795): (bar) connecting to tomcat failed (rc=-3, errors=1, client_errors=0).
285 [debug] ajp_reset_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (847): (bar) resetting endpoint with socket -1 (socket shutdown)
286 [debug] ajp_abort_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (817): (bar) aborting endpoint with socket -1
287 [debug] ajp_done::jk_ajp_common.c (3287): recycling connection pool for worker bar and socket -1
288 [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2991): Service error=-3 for worker=bar
289 [Wed Sep 06 04:32:49 2023] bar 192.168.157.130 0.101021
290 [debug] jk_servlet_normalize::jk_util.c (2184): URI on entering jk_servlet_normalize: [/foo]
291 [debug] jk_servlet_normalize::jk_util.c (2278): URI on exiting jk_servlet_normalize: [/foo]
292 [debug] map_uri_to_worker_ext::jk_uri_worker_map.c (1167): Attempting to map URI '/foo' from 4 maps
293 [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (977): Attempting to map context URI '/bar/*=bar' source 'JkMount'
294 [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (977): Attempting to map context URI '/foo/*=foo' source 'JkMount'
295 [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (977): Attempting to map context URI '/bar=bar' source 'JkMount'
296 [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (977): Attempting to map context URI '/foo=foo' source 'JkMount'
297 [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (1000): Found an exact match '/foo=foo'
298 [debug] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2821): Into handler jakarta-servlet worker=foo r->proxyreq=0
299 [debug] wc_get_worker_for_name::jk_worker.c (119): found a worker foo
300 [debug] wc_maintain::jk_worker.c (352): Maintaining worker bar
301 [debug] wc_maintain::jk_worker.c (352): Maintaining worker foo
302 [debug] wc_get_name_for_type::jk_worker.c (303): Found worker type 'ajp13'
303 [debug] init_ws_service::mod_jk.c (1178): Service protocol=HTTP/1.1 method=GET ssl=false host=(null) addr=192.168.157.1 name=192.168.157.130 port=80 auth=(null) user=(null) laddr=192.168.157.130 raddr=192.168.157.1 uaddr=192.168.157.1 uri=/fo        o
304 [debug] ajp_get_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (3356): (foo) acquired connection pool slot=0 after 0 retries
305 [debug] ajp_marshal_into_msgb::jk_ajp_common.c (680): (foo) ajp marshaling done
306 [debug] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2587): processing foo with 2 retries
307 [debug] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1718): (foo) no usable connection found, will create a new one.
308 [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (673): socket TCP_NODELAY set to On
309 [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (797): trying to connect socket 45 to 192.168.157.130:8309
310 [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (815): connect to 192.168.157.130:8309 failed (errno=13)
311 [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1064): (foo) Failed opening socket to (192.168.157.130:8309) (errno=13)
312 [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1724): (foo) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=13)
313 [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2774): (foo) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=1)
314 [debug] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2623): (foo) retry 1, sleeping for 100 ms before retrying
315 [debug] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1718): (foo) no usable connection found, will create a new one.
316 [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (673): socket TCP_NODELAY set to On
317 [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (797): trying to connect socket 45 to 192.168.157.130:8309
318 [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (815): connect to 192.168.157.130:8309 failed (errno=13)
319 [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1064): (foo) Failed opening socket to (192.168.157.130:8309) (errno=13)
320 [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1724): (foo) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=13)
321 [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2774): (foo) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=2)
322 [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2795): (foo) connecting to tomcat failed (rc=-3, errors=1, client_errors=0).
323 [debug] ajp_reset_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (847): (foo) resetting endpoint with socket -1 (socket shutdown)
324 [debug] ajp_abort_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (817): (foo) aborting endpoint with socket -1
325 [debug] ajp_done::jk_ajp_common.c (3287): recycling connection pool for worker foo and socket -1
326 [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2991): Service error=-3 for worker=foo
327 [Wed Sep 06 04:32:59 2023] foo 192.168.157.130 0.100528
```

When I test my applications on Mac desktop Safari (and also Chrome) like so,

> 1. http://192.168.157.130/bar
> 2. http://192.168.157.130/foo

Both cases throws the aforementioned error.
However, when I test the sites by including the port numbers:

> 1. http://192.168.157.130:8280/bar
> 2. http://192.168.157.130:8380/foo

both successfully display the test sites.

Configuration files

Apache Httpd (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName artemis.com

   JkMount /bar bar
   JkMount /bar/* bar

   JkMount /foo foo
   JkMount /foo/* foo
</VirtualHost>
```

Mod JK

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

#-- Path to workers.properties
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties

#-- Path to jk logs
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log

#-- Jk log level [debug/error/info]
JkLogLevel debug

#-- Jk log format
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "

#-- JkOptions for forwarding
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories

#-- JkRequestLogFormat set the request format
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"

# Add shared memory.
# This directive is present with 1.2.10 and
# later versions of mod_jk, and is needed for
# for load balancing to work properly
JkShmFile /var/cache/httpd/mod_jk/jk.shm
```

Workers file

```
worker.list=bar,foo

#-- @instance demo /bar (port 8280)
worker.bar.port=8209
worker.bar.host=192.168.157.130
worker.bar.type=ajp13

#-- @instance expo /foo (port 8380)
worker.foo.port=8309
worker.foo.host=192.168.157.130
worker.foo.type=ajp13
```

Tomcat is installed in /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.80
Tomcat instances are installed in /var/lib/tomcats

Tomcat Instance 'demo' (/var/lib/tomcats/demo)

```
<Server port="8205" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">  

<Connector port="8280" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443"
    maxParameterCount="1000"
/>                                                                    

<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
    address="192.168.157.130"
    port="8209"
    redirectPort="8443"
    maxParameterCount="1000"
    secretRequired=”false”
/>
```

Tomcat instance 'expo' (/var/lib/tomcats/expo)

```
<Server port="8305" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

<Connector port="8380" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443"
    maxParameterCount="1000"
/>                                                                    

<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
    address="192.168.157.130"
    port="8309"
    redirectPort="8443"
    maxParameterCount="1000"
    secretRequired=”false”
/>
```

Other Information

```
$ uname -a
Linux artemis 5.4.17-2136.322.6.2.el7uek.x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ ifconfig
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
  inet 192.168.157.130  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.157.255

$ vi /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.157.130 artemis.com

$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.20" 2023-07-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-11.0.20.0.8-1.0.1.el7_9) (build 11.0.20+8-LTS)
```

Developer machine

```
Apple Mac mini (2018), macOS Catalina, Intel Core i5
Hypervisor: VMWare Fusion v11.5.3
VM: Oracle Linux R7 U9
```